# how can handle multpile oauth request from frondend in single routr

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs

IS there any way i can dynamic take the platform info and process them,even when i tried accessing the value outside the function it is not working since it is a single route file

```
router.get(
  "/:platform",
  function data(req, res, next) {
     var platform = req.params.platform;
     next();
  },
  passport.authenticate("google", { scope: ["email"] })
);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can save the data in `req` and then run the middleware manually

This should work, but I didn't test it

```
router.get(
  "/:platform",
  function data(req, res, next) {
     req.platform = req.params.platform;
     next();
  },
  (req, res, next) => passport.authenticate(req.platform, { scope: ["email"] })(req, res, next)
);
```